# proxyquire TypeError: Datastore is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, proxyquire

I am trying to test the following piece of code.

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');

// Creates a client
const datastore = new Datastore({
  projectId: serviceConfig.projectId
});
```

My test file contains

```
  function MockDatastore (config) {
    this.projectId = config.projectId;
  }

  var datastoreStub = {Datastore:MockDatastore}

  return proxyquire('../../../app/persistence', {
    '@google-cloud/datastore': datastoreStub
  });
```

As per [1] this should be allowed.

[1] https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire/issues/63

Answer (score 3):

Since API change 2.x you should use this:

```
const { Datastore } = require("@google-cloud/datastore");
```

Then it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, that's what was needed!